# How to get left-click to show preview of windows in group in Plasma

Tags: 22.04, kde, plasma

Coming from Windows, I am used to being able to click on the icon of an application show a preview of all instances of windows of that application.

On plasma, it instead opens (=raises to the foreground) the corresponding windows in rotation, and I have to hover for more than a second(!) to see the preview.

Also, the preview doesn't show Window contents but only the icon.

Can both of these things be changed?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Right click taskbar, press "Configure", then change what's in the screenshot below
[image]

There is also a "Present Window" effect, which shows full screen window contents of the relevant windows.